# VueJS Condição de Classes

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Eu tenho um menu e queria saber se tem como eu fazer uma condição de **adicionar uma classe dependendo da classe filho**.

Por exemplo:

```
<ul :class="{ 'open' : TemClasseNoFilho }">
    <li v-for="item in list" :class="{ 'active' : $route.nome == item.rotaNome}">
          <a>{{ item.nome}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

> Nesse exemplo, gostaria de colocar a condição: "Insira classe "**Open**" em "**ul**" se o "**li**" tiver a classe "**active**"

Obrigado!

Comment: é so criar no data, e torna-la `true` ou `false`, ai voce vai verificar, se for `true`, ela existe, se for `false` não

Comment: Como assim, Rafael?

Answer (score 1):

Cria um dado no `computed` tipo assim:

```js
isOpen: function() {
  if (this.$els.li.className.match(/\active\b/)) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

e no template:

```html
<ul :class="isOpen ? 'open': ''">
    <li v-for="item in list" :class="{ 'active' : $route.nome == item.rotaNome}">
          <a>{{ item.nome}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```